# Where does the mist browser store the node log files?

Tags: mist, clients, ethereum-wallet-dapp, logs

Mist uses to launch it's own client (`geth` or `eth`) in the background.

Does it store the node's logs? If so, where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it does!

Mist [writes logs](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2495) to a file by default. The log files are rotated and stored in a platform-specific directory.

- On OS X, the latest log is `~/Library/Application Support/Mist/node.log`
- On Windows, it is `C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Roaming\Mist\node.log`
- On Linux, it's `~/.config/Mist/node.log`

There is also a button in the Mist menu that opens this folder.