# Error openning the Ethereum wallet win64 0-8-8 on Windows 10

Tags: mist, ethereum-wallet-dapp, nodes, windows, logs

I'm getting this error when opening the Ethereum Wallet x64 version 0.8.8 on Windows 10:

[image: screenshot error]

And then I see this window:

[image: screenshot splash]

I don't see any log file, but i see below Information in Windows Event log Security section:

```
A new process has been created.

Creator Subject:
    Security ID:        REDMOND\v-arkouk
    Account Name:       v-arkouk
    Account Domain:     REDMOND
    Logon ID:       0x2E1378

Target Subject:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       -
    Account Domain:     -
    Logon ID:       0x0

Process Information:
    New Process ID:     0x1224
    New Process Name:   C:\Users\v-arkouk\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum Wallet\binaries\Geth\unpacked\geth.exe
    Token Elevation Type:   %%1938
    Mandatory Label:        Mandatory Label\Medium Mandatory Level
    Creator Process ID: 0x3a3c
    Creator Process Name:   C:\Users\v-arkouk\Downloads\Ethereum-Wallet-win64-0-8-8\win-unpacked\Ethereum Wallet.exe
    Process Command Line:   "C:\Users\v-arkouk\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum Wallet\binaries\Geth\unpacked\geth.exe" version

Token Elevation Type indicates the type of token that was assigned to the new process in accordance with User Account Control policy.

Type 1 is a full token with no privileges removed or groups disabled.  A full token is only used if User Account Control is disabled or if the user is the built-in Administrator account or a service account.

Type 2 is an elevated token with no privileges removed or groups disabled.  An elevated token is used when User Account Control is enabled and the user chooses to start the program using Run as administrator.  An elevated token is also used when an application is configured to always require administrative privilege or to always require maximum privilege, and the user is a member of the Administrators group.

Type 3 is a limited token with administrative privileges removed and administrative groups disabled.  The limited token is used when User Account Control is enabled, the application does not require administrative privilege, and the user does not choose to start the program using Run as administrator.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the logs and post the raw contents, please.

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb updated the question with what I found

Comment: @Aram please find your node logs first, and add them to your question. See: [Where does the mist browser store the node log files?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3366/87)

Comment: I think there was some security issues with the domain that my computer was on. When I got off that domain, it worked. Thanks guys.

Comment: @Aram, glad you got it sorted.  Please, post a detailed answer and accept it.

Comment: [Can I answer my own question?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem was with the domain and domain security that my computer was joined.

After leaving that domain the Ethereum wallet opens just fine with no errors.